# Text not displaying vertically inside button

Tags: html, css, flexbox, vertical-alignment, elementor

I have checked every solution I can find listed on Stackoverflow for this common question and none are working for me. I have tried adjusting font-size, line-height, height, box-sizing, padding, vertical-align, display and position. I don't want to use absolute positioning because I want the container to adjust naturally to the size of the text.

[image: Screenshot of button element vertical alignment problem]

The text inside the inner most span of all button elements tends to slide off the top of its container (into padding territory) resulting in text that isn't vertically aligned centrally, see image above. I added `display: flex; align-items: flex-end` which pulled it in a tiny bit but hasn't fixed the problem. What is happening?

I am using a page builder so I will try to pull out the relevant CSS but I might miss something. Please use inspector on any button on the staging website to [check working code](https://staging.cascading-styles.com/maple/).

```css
.elementor-button-wrapper {box-sizing: border-box}
.elementor-button {
   line-height: 1.2em;
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 12px 24px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
.elementor-button-content-wrapper {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   line-height: 1.2em;
}
.elementor-button-text {
   display: flex;
   align-items: flex-end;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   line-height: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="elementor-button-wrapper">
  <a class="elementor-button">
     <span class="elementor-button-content-wrapper">
        <span class="elementor-button-text">
           Order Now
        </span>
     </span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Which Browser are you using, because in system (chrome latest) it does not like that

Comment: @YuvarajM I'm using Firefox and Chrome and they both look wrong!

Comment: I've just tried switching the font to sans-serif and it seems to display correctly aligned. Perhaps it is an issue with the font?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thought occurred to me to try a different font. I tried the default sans-serif as well as Montserrat and it seems to be displaying correctly. I didn't realise fonts could come with alignment issues like this!

Answer (score 3):

A couple of things to think about:

Use a button if it's a button. Don't try to masking      t a div as a button, because you will loose a lot of functionality, like hover state, tab order and things like that.

Second of all, always try to use as little HTML and CSS as possible. You have over-complicated the whole element.

Thirdly, and this is actually the solution: you had 1.2em as line-height, which means that you will automatically get a space underneath your text. A suggestion is to instead use padding inside the button to create space around the characters, so you never need to bother about how big the text is.

```css
.elementor-button {
   line-height: 1em;
   border: 1px solid;
   border-radius: 1em;
   padding: 0.5em 1em;
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button class="elementor-button">
   Order Now
</button>
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your comment. I am using a page builder so don't have control over the HTML structure or types of elements. I am aware this is a downside of using page builders but it is part of a considered decision. In this case the upsides balance the downsides.